# VB.net Translator using webscraping and google translate

Tags: html, vb.net, web-scraping

Hi all i'm fairly new to programming and have been trying to create a english to japanese translator. Im trying to accomplish this by extracting the HTML off google translate an using it. So far I seem to get the page source but Im not actually getting the translated text. This is my code;

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub TextTranslate(InputText)
        Try
            Dim URL = "https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=ja&text=" + InputText.text
            'Process.Start(URL)
            Dim StringOutput As String = ""
            Dim Response As WebResponse
            Dim Request As WebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(URL)
            Response = Request.GetResponse()
            Using sr As New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream())
                StringOutput = sr.ReadToEnd()
                sr.Close()
            End Using
            OutputText.Text = StringOutput

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message, "Error")

        End Try



    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Call TextTranslate(InputText)
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the URL, and the Rest of Your Code seems correct.
You have to find the HTML-Section of the resulting "StringOutput".

```
<div class="text-wrap tlid-copy-target"><div class="result-shield-container tlid-copy-target" tabindex="0"><span class="tlid-translation translation" lang="ja"><span title="" class="" contenteditable="false" tabindex="-1">仕事</span></span><span class="tlid-translation-gender-indicator translation-gender-indicator"></span><span class="tlid-trans-verified-button trans-verified-button" style="display:none" role="button"></span></div></div>
```

In the resulting HTML I used the Search term "Berufe" in German, and the Result is (in Japanese "仕事").

I don´t know if the Result is correct, not my Language.

To get Your results it is advice able to use String operations.

Find the Section i described before, and use the Class-Attribute of the HTML.
Search for this, "result-shield-container tlid-copy-target", and from there find the Text containing HTML-Element.

As a beginner in Programming, it would be a good exercise to get Familiar with String-Operations.

You can also rely on a Library or some other Helper Functions.

But here are meeting a couple of programming technics.
Visual Basic and HTML, and .NET-Framework.

HTML has nothing to do with any Language except it self.
To get a Good idea about HTML try some Exercises, with CSS and JavaScript.

With that You will get a good understanding how to and what to Manipulate in HTML.

Then get familiar with Visual Basic. In my humble Opinion, You should start learning "WPF = Windows Presentation Foundation" instead of "Windows Forms".

Both are similar, but WPF is much better...

Also in .NET there is the Possibility to use HTML-Objects from a loaded Page, to get an easier Way of Finding HTML-Elements.

Have fun Programming.

c.u. Zui from Hamburg, Germany

Comment: Hi Zui thanks for reading my post and giving it a go, its much appreciated.

Comment: One more question Zui, would you suggest to remove these few lines of code and replace it; `Using sr As New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream())
                StringOutput = sr.ReadToEnd()
                sr.Close()
            End Using`             as I believe this is just finding the source code an actually isn't obtaining the HTML elements Im looking for.

Comment: Nope. Let it like it is for now. The Concept is this: A Webbrowser is loading with the same Code the Webpages(-content) to the local Computer/RAM. Then it will create the Render of the Webpage in the UI. There is more to it, but that is the purpose of a Webbrowser. But to Work on the Content of the Page. The HTMl-Sourcecode (incl. Javascripts, Images, Videos etc.) is then Parsed and Converted to Class instances/ Objects. there You can much better do Operations and manipulations of the Content.

Comment: This technique is also used to add CSS into a rendered Webpage. So there is the DOM (Document Object Model) which is the Object and its containing Elements in HTML. That is the Standard. For You it is easy in WinForms to use the The "HtmlDocument"-Class. Or use the "HtmlAgilityPack". Please search for it in the Interwebs. :) I hope I explained it a little bit better.